# How do you clear a cached Playready license on an Android device?

Tags: android, drm, playready

Background:
When issuing Playready DRM licenses, you can specify an expiration time on the license. From what I understand, if the license hasn't expired, the license is stored somewhere on the client and subsequent requests can just use this license instead of making another drm request to obtain a new license.

On Mac and Windows these licenses are stored in specific directories like:
/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/PlayReady/mspr.hds (mac)
C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/PlayReady/mspr.hds (windows)

You can just remove these files in order to clear the stored licenses.

I wasn't able to find documentation on how to clear the licenses on mobile devices (Android or iOS). Could someone please advise?

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to clear license on ios?

Answer (score 1):

There are different implementation of PlayReady for Android devices, each of which potentially stores the PlayReady database in a different location. Your best bet is to contact the vendor of the PlayReady SDK that you use (if 3rd party) or simply use a filesystem browser to find the equivalent file on the Android device.